# ¿Son bienvenidas las preguntas cuya respuesta exigiría realmente, y directamente, enseñar español o una materia concreta del español?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Me explico: acabo de leer [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19327/how-to-use-importar-as-matters-to-someone) que a mi parecer, dado el nivel que **parece** tener el usuario que la escribe, debería ser más bien un motivo para mandarle a leer de nuevo el capítulo correspondiente de su libro de estudios (o referenciarle la consabida página de recursos para aprender español), en vez de hacerle una respuesta rápida sobre el verbo que pregunta.

El problema es que para responder adecuadamente a esa pregunta habría que explicarle un montón de cosas, no solo cómo funcionan los verbos reflexivos. Que no me parecería mal, pero me queda la duda de si realmente éste *StackExchange* "va de eso".
Básicamente es una impresión subjetiva que bien podría estar equivocada, pero siempre tuve la impresión (valga la redundancia) que aquí se busca más bien resolver dudas concretas después de un esfuerzo por parte del que pregunta, no dar clases de español.

¿Mi impresión es correcta o este tipo de preguntas también son parte de lo "teóricamente" aceptado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes questions like the one you cite get a response suggesting that the OP should clarify what steps s/he has taken to understand, or alternatively the OP is asked to suggest what they think the answer is. In the case of the one you cite even I as an English speaker could see a lot of basic problems and I agree with you that there is a limit to how much the native speakers can do here. I would think it reasonable if people who answer here took a harder line sometimes. And apologies that this is in English.

Comment: Do not apologize for using English, mdewey!!

Comment: I was going to say the same, no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hay detalles del lenguaje, como el de la pregunta que citas, que son siempre difíciles para alguien que aprende español cuyo lenguaje materno es el inglés. Ciertamente, sería demasiado presuntuoso tratar de dar una explicación académica del concepto, debido a que un buen texto puede hacer un mejor trabajo. Sin embargo, una explicación general puede contribuir, al menos potencialmente, para que una cantidad grande de personas se puedan beneficiar.

En el caso de otros Stacks, muchas veces encuentro respuestas a preguntas que tengo sobre mi trabajo. Muchas veces, la pregunta ha sido respondida varios años antes y tiene miles de visitas y no necesariamente son respondidas de manera académica. No siempre encuentro la respuesta exacta pero he encontrado simples ideas o alguna guía que me llevan a resolver un problema que de otro modo hubiera sido más difícil.